# Error: Could not find artifacts for contract

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-test

I'm new to ethereum development and trying to test `SimpleStorage` contract using truffle:

I created file structure using `turffle init` and here is the files sturctur:

```
~/Desktop/truffle-test$ tree .
.
├── build
│   └── contracts
│       └── SimpleStorage.json
├── contracts
│   └── SimpleStorage.sol
├── migrations
│   └── 3_deploy_simpleStorage.js
├── test
│   └── simpleStorage-test.js
└── truffle-config.js
```

my `simpleStorage-test.js` is:

```
const simpleStorage = artifacts.require('../contracts/SimpleStorage.sol');

contrcat('SimpleStorage', ()=> {
    it('should update data', async ()=> {
        const storage = await simpleStorage.new();
        await storage.set(10);
        const data = await storage.get();
        assert(data.toString()==='10');
    });
});
```

I can migrate the contract and I see transaction appear on Ganache-GUI but when I run `truffle test` I get:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

ReferenceError: contrcat is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pc/Desktop/truffle-test/test/simpleStorage-test.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:390:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:387:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:961:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/Test.js:157:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/Test.js:156:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/test/run.js:56:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.4.26 (core: 5.4.26)
Node v16.13.0
```

I tried differnt things like `SimpleStorage`  instead of `../contracts/SimpleStorage.sol` in `tartifacts.require`  but none solved the issue. So appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a typo in your code. Replace `contrcat` with `contract`. This variable is defined by the truffle framework.

Comment: ah, stupid me! thanks for the tip.